# Initializing new Fragment in Tabhost/Viewpager construct not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an activity holding a sidebar navigation and a place holder for my fragments. (-> on clicking the sidemenu I switch fragments ...)
One of those fragments (called TabFragment) uses tabs, which are populated with (List)fragments (similar to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html example, but I dont use Actionbar Tabs, but the old ones).

The first time I show the TabFragment, everything works. The TabFragment is called, there I "populate the tabs" (--> like in the example above I actually just populate the viewpager) with my ListFragments (there onCreateView etc. is called). It works.

Then I try to put another instance of the TabFragment on the screen (I need to show different lists and want to be able to use the back button -> backstack), the TabFragment is called, I add the Fragments to the TabsAdapter, but no lifecycle methode of the ListFragments is called ... why?

[I know that this isn't the best way to go and there are plenty of options to rewrite this to get the same effect, but since it works the first time I'd really like to know where this is going wrong]

**Activity Code**

```
     Fragment search1 = new MainListFr();
     Bundle test1 = new Bundle();
     test1.putInt(Constants.FRAGMENT_SEARCH_ID, 1);
     g1.setArguments(test1);

     m_fragmentTransaction = m_fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     m_fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, search1, "search1");
     m_fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("search1");
     m_fragmentTransaction.commit();

     m_layout.toggleSidebar();
```

**MainListFr (=TabFragment)**

```
public class MainListFr extends Fragment {
   TabHost m_tabHost;
   ViewPager m_viewPager;
   TabsAdapter m_tabsAdapter;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
         final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stub_main, null);

      m_tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
      m_tabHost.setup();

      m_viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.main_pager);

      m_tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), m_tabHost, m_viewPager);

      View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_left, null);
      View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_right, null);

      Bundle args = getArguments();

      m_tabsAdapter.addTab(m_tabHost.newTabSpec("topsearch").setIndicator(v1),
            SearchListFr.class, args);
      m_tabsAdapter.addTab(m_tabHost.newTabSpec("topsuggestion").setIndicator(v2),
            SuggestionListFr.class, args);

      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         m_tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
      }

      return view;
   }
}
```

**SearchListFr (=ListFragment)**

```
   private ListView m_list = null;
   private View m_progress = null;
   private View m_noRes = null;

   SearchAdapter m_searchAdapter = null;
   private Vector<SearchItem> m_searchList = null;

   private int m_searchId = 0;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
         final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_videolist, null);

      m_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fr_videolist_list);
      m_progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_root);
      m_noRes = view.findViewById(R.id.noresult_root);


      m_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      m_noRes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      m_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      Bundle args = getArguments();
      if (args != null) {
         m_searchId = args.getInt(Constants.FRAGMENT_SEARCH_ID);
      }

      // load the content here (asynctask)
      new LoadSearchList().execute();

      return view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(_savedInstanceState);

      m_searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(getActivity());
      m_list.setAdapter(m_searchAdapter);
      m_list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
      m_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   }
```

**TabsAdapter**

```
/**
 * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
 * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost.  It relies on a
 * trick.  Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
 * Intent that each tab will show.  This is not sufficient for switching
 * between pages.  So instead we make the content part of the tab host
 * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
 * view to show as the tab content.  It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
 * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
 * tab changes.
 */
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```